# Change encrypted internal HD permissions to prevent password prompts

Tags: permission, encryption, hdd

I have an iMac (running OS X 10.11.3) with a dual disk setup. A ssd for the OS (with Filevault turned on) and a HDD for storage that is formatted OS X Extended and Encrypted.

The intention is to symlink some user directories onto the storage HD.

The problem that I have is when I try to delete files on the storage HD I am prompted for a password (the user password as opposed to the password for the encryption). Also when I move files on the storage HD they are essentially copied as opposed to moved.

I have tried:

```
sudo chown -Rv username directory
```

but that hasn't worked.

I have also tried changing the Sharing and Permissions privilege settings to Read & Write for all folders and files but that hasn't worked either.

Anybody with any advice would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

OK, I found a solution. If anybody would like to correct my approach please let me know.

```
With the storage drive (get info) -> 
Sharing & Permisions -> 
Checked 'Ignore ownership on this volume'
```

The next step might have been made redundant by the previous step, but I also did the following:

```
Directory on storage drive with user directories -> 
Sharing & Permission -> 
My User Profile, Read & Write
```

This appears to have done the job, can delete and move items as expected.